# Umask not respected in OCFS2 filesystem

Tags: umask, drbd

I encountered some strange behavior on a machine that uses a replicated block device (via DRBD) along with OCFS2 to allow concurrent mounts on multiple machines. The issue, in short, is that new files and directories created within this filesystem do not respect the `umask`.

Please consider the following:

```
$> cd /mountpoint
$> umask
0002

$> mkdir testdir
$> touch test.txt
$> su
#> umask
0022

#> mkdir testdir2
#> touch test2.txt
#> ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- (...) test2.txt
drwxrwxrwx (...) testdir
drwxrwxrwx (...) testdir2
-rw-rw-rw- (...) test.txt

#> getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: me
# group: me
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

#> cat /etc/mtab
(...)
/dev/drbd0 /mountpoint ocfs2 rw,_netdev,heartbeat=local 0 0
```

Hopefully the above is sufficient to know that there are no ACLs in play. This happens for both privileged and unprivileged users, and it **does not** occur outside of the OCFS2 filesystem.

So far my research on the topic has turned up no known issues with OCFS2 (or DRBD for that matter). Are there other tests I can run to narrow down the issue? Is anyone aware of why this might be taking place? Thank you for your time.

[I would have tagged under `ocfs2`, but that tag does not yet exist.]

Comment: it appears this wouldn't be the first time ocfs2 has had a bug like that.  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ocfs2.user/3439.  That was 2009, so it surely got fixed eventually, and yours is probably a different bug with the same symptom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this wouldn't be the first time ocfs2 has had a bug like that.  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ocfs2.user/3439.  That was 2009, so it surely got fixed eventually, and yours is probably a different bug with the same symptom.

I'd report it to ocfs2's bug tracker, which appears to be at https://oss.oracle.com/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=OCFS2

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards that list thread. I will attempt to mount without ACLs, as was mentioned in the thread, and file a report of my own.

Comment: Confirmed: mounting without ACLs resolves the issue.